# Problem with Windows Mouse user32.dll movement and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dllimport, user32, mouse-position

I am using user32.dll in Unity to write to the mouse's movement. I realized the cursor must be operating in Windows screen space, and I cannot figure out how to get it to operate only within the bounds of the Unity Game Window or Unity screenspace. When I try to set the mouse position based on Unity World or Screen Coordinates I get undesired results. I tried added an offset to the values but this only works when the camera is not zoomed in and the game window is full screen. I am new to coding but I really need some help as to how to be able to lock the cursor's position to position in the unity world/screen space when certain conditions in the game are met.

The second problem is I cannot undo the restriction of the mouse's movement from my script. Even after I stop running the game the mouse stays within the parameters set in the code. (Not desirable!)

Thankyou for your time!

I have looked at many different posts online but some of them are above my head. This is the first time I have used code not in the Unity API, so trying to understand how the Windows classes function and such is going very slowly.

```
public bool MOUSELOCK;
public bool Buttonpress;
public Button button;
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ClipCursor(ref RECT lpRect);
// Start is called before the first frame update
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}


void Start(){

    MOUSELOCK = false;
    Buttonpress = false;
}

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData){


        MOUSELOCK = true;

}

public void OnClicked(){



    Debug.Log ("Clicked true");


    if (MOUSELOCK == true) {

        Debug.Log ("Clicked trueCON");
        RECT cursorLimits;

        cursorLimits.Left = 40;
        cursorLimits.Top = 30;
        cursorLimits.Right = Screen.width - 8;
        cursorLimits.Bottom = Screen.height + 2;
        ClipCursor (ref cursorLimits);




        }
}



    }
```

Comment: why are you using User32.dll?  There are builtin systems in Unity for this...  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html

Comment: I began using it because I wanted to get the cursor to move to the position of a gameobject. There are ways to lock the movement of a gameobject to the mouseposition but not vice versa so I used this User32.dll set cursor position code! But I think it is functioning in windows screen space and disregarding the borders of the game window. I found a way to "fake clicks" using Execute.Events, so I think I will rework m mechanic instead of fighting with the User32.dll stuff.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to create a gui mouse, essentially lock the mouse and hide it.  Create a UI object to represent the mouse, then using the mouse delta's you can move this UI object around.  If you need to lock it to a gameobjects position, then you just update it to the correct location using `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint`  and setting the UI mouse to that location.  All click events should then be based off of this objects screenPoint instead of the Input.mouse.position.  This would then allow you to simulate a mouse in your game, confined to your screen, using your screen space.